# Google docs post table from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I have created a textarea field in my google apps spreadsheet table.html.

```
<textarea  name="tableS" id="tableS"></textarea>
```

Also i make a function which place table in HTML format to this texarea

```
        function updateUrl(myArray) {
            var results, tr, td;
            results = "<table border=\"1\" style=\"table-layout: fixed; width: 100%\">";
            for (var i = 1, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
                tr = myArray[i];
                results += "<tr>";
                for (var y = 0, leng = tr.length; y < leng; y++) {
                    td = tr[y];
                    results += "<td>" + td + "</td>";
                }
                results += "</tr>";
            }
            results += "<\/table><br \/> <br \/>";

            document.getElementById("tableS").value = results;
}
```

Then i trying to replace  on submit predefined text in my google docs template with textarea tables as html,

```
copyBody.replaceText('Passwords', e.table);
```

but i get in template pure text with tags

[image]

, but i need to get table formatted as html

[image]

How to do that?

Comment: HTML in a textarea will display as **HTML** - no great surprises there.

Comment: You can only have plain text in a textarea. If you want the table to be rendered in the screen, you could just add it to the page directly.

Comment: Please show an example how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to convert the HTML to an image, and then insert the image.  You can't put HTML markup directly into a Google Doc, and have it be rendered.  You are creating a table with HTML, but you can create a table for a Google Doc with the `Document` and `Table` class and sub class.

[Google Documentation - Table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table)

So, don't use HTML.  It won't work.  Use the `Table` class, build a table with the `Table` methods, then insert a Table into the Doc.

Comment: No you wrong understand my question. I need post table as html into google docs on submit